# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1020Library'. > Could not expand ZIP 'play-services-ads-10.2.0.aar'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just started learning android studio and I have created a simple app but when I was about to sign the APK I've got this error message.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1020Library'.

> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\yugio\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-ads\10.2.0\play-services-ads-10.2.0.aar'.

I do not know what to do; and I've tried the directory permissions and it did not work. I'm running Windows 10 Pro.

Here is manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" android:label="Verification Status" />
</application>
```

and this is my Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.paradoxygo.yugiohduellinkscheat"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
}
```

Comment: add `multiDexEnabled true` then `clean-rebuild` and sync

Comment: Could you please explain more how to add it and where, i'm new to mobile development thank you

Comment: after `testInstrumentationRunner` add `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it doesn't look MultiDex error , is it?

Comment: @Prashant no . #Yass set `ads:10.0.1` instead of current